# send mail including file attachment

Tags: php

Mail is being sent with file attachment but it's not possible to open it.

what is the problem please solve this.

```
<?php

    $file_name=$_FILES['Resume']['name'];
    $file_size=$_FILES['Resume']['size'];
    $file_temp=$_FILES['Resume']['tmp_name'];
    
    $to = 'renu_activa@yahoo.co.in';
    $subject = 'Test email with attachment'; 
    $from=$_POST['First'];
    $random_hash = md5(date('r', time()));
    $headers = "From: $from\r\nReply-To: $from";
    $headers .= "\r\nContent-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"PHP-mixed-".$random_hash."\"";
    $data = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents("$file_temp")));
    ob_start(); 
    ?> 
    --PHP-mixed-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>
    Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>"
    
    --PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>  
    Content-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-1" 
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
    
    Hello World!!! 
    This is simple text email message. 
    
    --PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>  
    Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1" 
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
    
    <h2>Hello World!</h2> 
    <p>This is something with <b>HTML</b> formatting.</p> 
    --PHP-mixed-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>
    Content-Type: $file_type; name=$file_name
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
    Content-Disposition: attachment
    
    <?php echo $data; ?>
    --PHP-mixed-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>-- 
    
    <?php 
    //copy current buffer contents into $message variable and delete current output buffer 
    $message = ob_get_clean(); 
    //send the email 
    $mail_sent = @mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );//if the message is sent successfully print "Mail sent". Otherwise print "Mail failed" 
    echo $mail_sent ? "Mail sent" : "Mail failed";
            ?>
```

Comment: I suggest that you use PHPmailer phpmailer.worxware.com

Comment: I can highly recommend [the Mail module of the zeta components](http://zetacomponents.org/documentation/trunk/Mail/tutorial.html) for sending mails with attachements. Will make your life a whole lot easier.

Comment: @AL-Kateb what u mean to say? And where i use PHPmailer phpmailer.worxware.com?

Comment: I am using this code and mail is being send but file is not opening.

Answer (score 2):

You don't build your own MIME emails. Use [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/) or [Swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/), which do almost everything for you. You can replace you entire script with about 5 or 6 lines of code.

And best of all, they'll give you far better error messages/diagnostics than the pathetically stupid mail() function ever will.

Also The Geekmail PHP library makes it easy to add attachments to emails

Comment: Please someone try to help me out.

Comment: read the documentation. there are examples. and google for examples

Answer (score 0):

what is "mysql_error"?  i think the correct syntax for you die statement is

```
die(mysql_error());
```

or

```
die($mysql_error);
```